# Is there a way to distinguish between connection timeout and read timeout in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, connection-timeout

Currently in angular the **$http** call is having only read timeout. So If the server is down and the angular app will wait for the timeout value even though the server connection is not established. Connection timeout can be identified within few millisecond after opening xhr using xhr readystates. **Is there any way to listen to connect timeout in Angular?**

Comment: you can timeout an xhr abort (for say, 1000ms) and clear the timeout in the onchange.

Comment: `$http` uses xhr - is there a reason why would want to know that?

Comment: In my application i have 30 sec as readtimeout for one service call so aangular is taking this as connection timeout and waiting for 30 sec to responsd, even if the server is down. Let me know whether i can give 1 sec as connection timeout through **$httpProvider**

Comment: define `server down` in status code terms

Comment: server down means, request url from angular js is not addressed by server/jvm and so the request failed with status 0 after 30 secs.

In my application service layer is running in java.

Comment: you could implement a ping request to know if the server is down or not.

Comment: Ok thanks for your input, but i want to know if connect timeout can be brodcasted by angular in any means